# Android App 50 percent width

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am trying to build a little Android App and I need two `LinearLayout` side by side. (50/50)

How it looks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9yCF.png

I already try to use: `android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"` but it didn't work.

This is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/part">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="9pt"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:background="#ff7f7f7f"
    android:id="@+id/head">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="123456789"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:paddingStart="3pt"
        android:paddingLeft="3pt"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:singleLine="false" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/head"
    android:background="#ffff0100" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/head"
    android:background="#fffcff00" />
```

How it should look:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tup01.png

Comment: You can't use weights in a relative layout.

Comment: One trick I've used in the past is create an empty view (full height, 0 width) and center it horizontally in the `RelativeLayout`.  Then, you can use `alignParentLeft` and `toLeftOf` for the left half, and vice versa for the right half.

Comment: Thanks to all, for the answers. I love this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have one more `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation below your `@+id/head` LinearLayout.
Set its width to `match_parent`. Keep the last two LinearLayouts inside the new LinearLayout and have `android:layout_weight=0.5` for both. Something like:

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <LinearLayout> </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
      ...
      android:orientation:"horizontal"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:weight="0.5"
            android:width="0dp" 
            ... />
         </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:weight="0.5"
            android:width="0dp" 
            ... />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It works, thank you. So Simple and you to fast for stackoverflow, i can't mark you question as the result, at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `layout_weight` with `RelativeLayout`s children. Put/Wrap both `LinearLayout`s in another `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this code...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/part"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/head"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="9pt"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#ff7f7f7f"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="3pt"
        android:paddingStart="3pt"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="123456789"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/head"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffff0100"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fffcff00"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```